# How to get the top menu to the left on frontage on RWD theme?

Tags: rwd

On my RWD theme, I have no category on the left side of the front page. But if I click on the top menu to a category, I get a category on my left side. How can I get the same top menu on the left of the index of my website, as i have on my category?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are referring to layered navigation...

If so, go into the category in the admin panel and set 'Is Anchor' to 'Yes'. Then you will have layered navigation in the sidebar on those category pages.